# Setting up Autoreply outside office hours on Gmail

Tags: javascript, gmail

I need to set up an auto responder for my Gmail account outside office hours, and I added this code to my Gmail account using Google scripts:

```js
function autoReply() {
var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if ([6].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 0 && hour < 10) || (day == 5 && hour >= 19)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread()){
      threads[i].reply("I am out of office. Your email will not seen until Monday morning.");
      threads[i].markRead();
      threads[i].markImportant();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, it's not sending an autoreply when emails are sent to my account:
I need it to send auto-replies on Saturday all day and Sunday through Friday only outside office hours.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this script to send an autoreply all day Saturday, and Sunday through Friday outside of office hours, change this line:

```
if ([6].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 0 && hour < 10) || (day == 5 && hour >= 19)) {
```

to:

```
if ([6].indexOf(day) > -1 || (hour < 10) || (hour >= 19)) {
```

the way it is coded now, it only replies on saturday, on sunday before 10, and on friday after 7pm.  it won't reply any other day.